# Why didn't The Doctor regenerate into 11th incarnation naked?

Tags: doctor-who

Regeneration from 10th to 11th was devastating. It almost destroyed TARDIS from inside. Why didn't it burn or destroy his clothes? Any specific nature of clothes? Any canonical statement saying that he was wearing holographic clothes? Or, any other thing?

Comment: Because of the rating?

Comment: @Sergio Nah. We've seen him naked in *The Time of The Doctor*.

Comment: The Doctor is connected to the TARDIS in a number of mysterious ways, and it seems to "regenerate" along with him at times.  Just my own personal assumption when I was watching the show, but could it be that his regeneration isn't actually destructive to his environment, but that the TARDIS specifically is effected by it?  After all, multiple regenerations have happened in close proximity to humans, who remained completely unharmed.

Comment: His Earth mother sewed his clothes from the super-blanket they found him in. I mean, wait...

Comment: @Nerrolken http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/42835/effect-of-the-tenth-doctor-s-regeneration-on-the-tardis

Comment: @SachinShekhar Interesting, but it doesn't necessarily negate the idea.  If I build an "explosive" burst of psychic energy, it will still only effect those things which are psychically linked to me.  The "regeneration energy" may operate in a way that bypasses normal matter like clothes, but still effects the TARDIS on a psychic, temporal, or other level.

Comment: Maybe the energy flows mainly out of his hands, and possibly the top of his head, but not that much flows out of other parts of his skin? When the Eleventh was starting to regenerate he was able to blow up Daleks by pointing his hands at them, but his clothes didn't burn off either.

Comment: It's a perfectly good question but I can't think of any canonical answer other than, "Nope!" Regeneration and its consequences appear to follow no discernible rules. For example, 10's regeneration into 11 is the first one, ever, to be destructive in any way to its surroundings. Either way, however, regeneration has never apparently affected the Doctor's clothing.

Comment: @Nerrolken: re psychic energy, maybe, but it seemed fairly effective against Dalek ships in *The Time of the Doctor*.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, the 10th was the 11th and the 11th regenerated twice. The half-human Doctor that went to the "Pete's World" Earth did regenerate nude. The second regeneration (to Matt Smith's Doctor) ended with Matt Smith in Ten's shirt and tie (looking worse for wear). Since he dressed himself in the Eleventh hour while discarding the "raggedy" clothes, they did not appear to be holographic.

[image: Picture of Matt Smith as The Doctor from The Eleventh Hour; Doctor Who - BBC]

Comment: The half-human guy wasn't really one of "The Doctor's" incarnations, but rather a duplicate created from his severed hand, which was naturally naked because hands don't wear clothes. The Doctor's 12th incarnation just happened to look exactly like his 11th (both looked like David Tennant), and was still wearing the same suit, because he did the trick of using the beginning of the regeneration to heal himself and then siphoning off the rest of the regeneration energy into the hand, which (somehow) prevented a change in appearance, though we later learned he had technically used up a "life".

Comment: @hypno a two way biological metacrises, but presumably only possible due to residual regeneration energy. It was still "one" regeneration.

Comment: Yes, my point was just that the Doctor didn't really "regenerate nude" there, *he* just regenerated into a healed version of David Tennant wearing the same suit as before, but this regeneration had the byproduct of creating a separate individual from his hand who started out nude (not because any clothes were burned off as Sachin was talking about, just because there were no clothes for the hand to grow into).

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with you. I'm saying we have seen a naked regeneration of the 11th incarnation. (See title of question). :)